# Android studio 3MB rest call takes too long

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm making an Android app and I'm doing a 3MB rest API json call, which roughly takes about 30 seconds. Of course this is way too slow.

I guess i can store the json string in a SQLite db. But the problem is that the json data changes frequently. So i would have to check if the data changed every time the app launches or something? Maybe there's another way?

Does anyone have some tips to fasten this 30 second process?

I've been googling around but didn't really find a solution, I guess my google skills suck.

Comment: there are http headers to stop the request if nothing changed. see `if-modified-since` and `if-none-match`

Comment: Does the JSON data come from your server or a foreign server?

Comment: it comes from my server.

Comment: @DenseCrab I'm not sure how feasible this is or _exactly_ how this would be done but perhaps allow the android app to request diffs from the server so that instead of pulling the whole response, you only get back the changes from the previous data. Of course, you will have to allow the app to make a full pull from the server at some point (when a user first starts it up).

Comment: @DenseCrab you might be able to try using gzip on your server as it might compress your json response down to something more reasonable.